# Using HTTP Post between 2 Java servlets

Tags: java, http, servlets, http-post

I have setup a java servlet which accepts parameters from the URL and have it working properly:

```
public class GetThem extends HttpServlet {

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   throws IOException, ServletException
{
    try {

            double lat=Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("lat"));
            double lon=Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("lon"));
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println(lat + " and " + lon);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }       
}
```

So visiting this link:
http://www.example.com:8080/HttpPost/HttpPost?lat=1&lon=2 would output:

```
  "1.0 and 2.0"
```

I'm currently calling it from another java program using this code:

```
try{
            URL objectGet = new URL("http://www.example.com:8080/HttpPost/HttpPost?lat=" + Double.toString(dg.getLatDouble()) + "&lon=" + Double.toString(dg.getLonDouble()));
            URLConnection yc = objectGet.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                    yc.getInputStream()));
            in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
            yc.getInputStream()));
            ...
```

Now I want to change it so that I'm not using the URL parameters to pass this data to the server.  I want to send much larger messages to this server.  I am aware that I need to use http post rather than http get to achieve this but am not sure how to do it.

Do I need to change anything on the server side which is receiving data?  What do I need to do on the client side which is posting this data?

Any help would be greatly appreciate thanks.
Ideally I'd like to send this data in JSON format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below there's sample from the first link found by "`java HTTP POST example`" in google.

```
try {
    // Construct data
    StringBuilder dataBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    dataBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode("key1", "UTF-8")).append('=').append(URLEncoder.encode("value1", "UTF-8")).
       append(URLEncoder.encode("key2", "UTF-8")).append('=').append(URLEncoder.encode("value2", "UTF-8"));

    // Send data
    URL url = new URL("http://hostname:80/cgi");
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(dataBuilder.toString());
    wr.flush();

    // Get the response
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        // Process line...
    }
    wr.close();
    rd.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yes, perhaps I posted here a little prematurely.  I was getting confused by the Apache HTTPClient and URLConnection, which one to use, etc.  I also ran into trouble because the API for HTTPClient changed from V3 to V4, but I was using tutorials for V3.

I got it working now using URLConnection.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using HTTPClient instead of handling connections and streams. Check http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  I looked into this (the version 4 tutorial) but decided to go with URLConnection because:

1) I'm just learning how to program and handling connections myself will give me a better understanding than using HTTPClient.
2) I'm also working on an Android app.  HTTPClient was depreciated by google and they recommend URLConnection.  I'd like to connect the same way between android and other servlets to keep things simple.